# How to import multiple Dart files in the same folder

Tags: dart, flutter

As the question is self-explaining, assume in the folder I have multiple Dart file. Instead of importing file by file (for example `import 'screens/screen_1.dart'; import 'screens/screen_2.dart';...`), I want to batch import (such as `import 'screens/*.dart'`) but it doesn't work.

Do you know Dart allows us to do such batch import?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dart imports don't support importing multiple files at once.

What you can do is creating a library that exports other libraries

`screens.dart`

```
export 'screens/screen_1.dart';
export 'screens/screen_2.dart';
export 'screens/screen_3.dart';
```

`foo.dart`

```
import 'screens.dart';
```